# Шаблонный класс и память

Tags: c++

1)Всегда ли инстанс шаблонного класса занимает место в памяти?

```
template<class A>
class C{};

C<int> c1; 
C<double> c2;
```

Я говорю не о памяти выделенной для объекта, а памяти которую занимает класс (его статические поля, методы). Ведь на сколько я знаю типы существуют только на этапе компиляции. И код

```
int a = 10;
```

и

```
class INT {int a = 10;}
INT i;
```

По размеру не будут отличаться. Наличие опредления класса в исходном коде не изменит размер исполняемого файла.

2)Занимает ли память каждая инстанс шаблонного класс в котором есть статические поля?

```
template<class A>
class C{static constexpr int i = sizeof(A);};
    
C<int> c1;
C<double> c2;
```

Занимают ли место в памяти функции-члены шаблонного класса, шаблонные классы
использует одни и те же функции-члены для своих инстанс или нет?

```
template<class A>
class C{public: A fuu(A a){return a;}};
    
C<int> c1;
C<double> c2;
```

Comment: *Я имею ввиду не память выделенную для создания объекта, а память необходимую для самого, класса.* Что вы имеете в виду? В коде будет выделена память для `c1` и `c2`, но что вы понимаете под *память необходимую для самого, класса*? Что именно вы понимаете под словом *инстанс*?

Comment: @Harry генерация кода класса по шаблону для конкретных параметров. С<int>c1,c2; - одно инстанцирование. С<int> c1; C<double> c2; C<int> c3 - два инстанцирования. Это не так называется? Подскажите как верно если для этого есть термин.

Comment: @Harry память необходимая для самого класса это память которую класс занимает непосредственно в исполняемом файле.

Comment: Для понимания не легче... Есть объекты класса, есть статические члены класса, есть код функций класса... Что понимать под памятью, *которую класс занимает непосредственно в исполняемом файле*? Например, если объекты класса не глобальные, то *в исполняемом файле* они как таковые память не занимают. Но в этом файле будет непредсказуемого размера код, который будет их создавать — его учитывать?

Comment: @Harry Я не понимаю к чему вы клоните. Меня интересует память которую занимает класс, не объекты этого класса. Память занимаемая классом - статические поля и функции. И все это в контексте шаблонов. Если  одно статическое поле в классе занимает 1мб, это ок. Если этот класс шаблонный. Это может стать проблемой.

Comment: Вы и в вопросе, и в комментариях говорите о занимаемой памяти *в исполняемом файле*. Не в оперативной памяти, а именно в исполняемом файле. А это совершенно разные вещи...

Comment: @Harry спасибо, что указали на это. Не знаю даже задумывался ли я об этом. Но я понимал, что говорю не об оперативной памяти.

Comment: Оперативную память тоже. Статическим переменным будет выделена память при загрузке программы. И исполняемый файл также грузится в оперативную память - блок кода. Да, может не сразу, может кусками, но в общем случае - больший размер исполняемого файла - большее потребление оперативной памяти. Просто обычно размер исполняемого файла значительно меньше, чем размер данных, которыми оперирует код, поэтому им пренебрегают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Да, всегда. И зависит не от размера, а от сигнатуры - списка типов, с которыми создается. `int` и `unsigned int` тоже по размеру не отличаются, но это разные типы с разным поведением и т.д.
2. Статическое поле будет создано для каждого инстанса шаблона. В вашем примере - 2 статических переменных. При этом размер объекта класса будет равен 1 байт - требование стандарта. По замечанию @Mikhailo - объект пустого класса имеет ненулевой размер.
   А вот код функций сгенерируется для обоих инстансов. Для вашего шаблона:

```
template<class A>
class C
{ 
    static constexpr int i = sizeof(A);
    A fuu(A a) {return a;}    
};

C<int> c1;
C<double> c2;
```

будет сгенерировано

```
static constexpr int C<int>::i;
static constexpr int C<double>::i;

C<int>::fuu(int a);
C<double>::fuu(double a);
```

Для каждого инстанса также будут сгенерированы конструкторы/деструкторы по-умолчанию.
Этот сгенерированный код будет занимать место в вашем исполняемом файле и памяти при загрузке.

Это описано для общего случая. Есть вариации в случаях явного и неявного инстанцирования и реализации компилятором оптимизатора - но это тонкости.

Comment: Ко второму вопросу — размер каждого экземпляра будет как минимум 1 байт. Даже объект пустого класса имеет ненулевой размер. Есть такое требование, чтоб массивы объектов можно было иметь. Вот, убедитесь: https://ideone.com/Q6Lb15

Comment: Mikhailo и Alex F - да, согласен, я просто отнес это к оптимизации и особенностям. Это уже варианты, не имеющие отношения конкретно к шаблонам - это правила, распространяющиеся на все конструкции языка. Но ответ поправил.